# render :edit does not work as I would expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following two methods in a rails controller:

```
  def edit
    @blog = Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    blog = Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])
    user = User.find_by!(id: params[:user_id])

    blog.update_attributes(blog_update_params)
    if blog.save
      flash[:success] = 'Updated Blog'
      redirect_to user_blog_path(user.id, blog.id)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

Lets assume this update fails, ok so you should `render :edit` which means, in my mind, that we should pass the id of the blog to the edit action and re-render the form. This in turn will display any errors:

```
<div class="container-sm">
  <%= form_for @blog, :url => user_blog_path(current_user.id, @blog.id), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <h1>Edit <%= @blog.title %></h1>
        <p class="text-muted">Want to change the name? Never a simpler place!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <%= render :partial => 'form_errors', :object => @blog %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render :partial => 'blog_form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <%= f.submit "Update", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My edit form above, pretty basic. pretty simple.  every one is happy. If we still live under the assumption that the update has failed it should re-render this form, but the issue is: `undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass` which happens at:

```
 <%= form_for @blog, :url => user_blog_path(current_user.id, @blog.id), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Every tutorial, form post or stack question states this is how you re-render the form to display any errors.

When I drop a `binding.pry` above the `render :edit` and then copy and paste to make it physically render the edit action, the `@blog` is the one that is blank. current_user contains the current user, which in this case is me, `@blog` is nil.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting `@blog` in your controller action - you're setting `blog`.

It needs to be an instance variable to be passed to the view for rendering, just like it is in the edit action.

Unrelated, but you can simplify `Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])` to just `Blog.find(params[:id])`.